# sort a numbered List with Jade

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, pug

I would like to sort a numbered list by pressing a button but the Filter should stay in use. The order is not important. My wish is only to sort it in different ways. I found here an example to sort a list "http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/SjWXU/" but I don't find a way to use it for my list in jade. Maybe somebody can help me with the button and the code.
To get an impression of the list-idea:
http://www.oldie-ponderosa.de/sort.png
My code in the index.jade:

```
block content
ol#actions(data-role="listview",data-filter="true", data-filter-placeholder="Filter", data-inset="true")
    - each action in actions
        li(id=action._id)
            a(href="/edit/#{action._id}")
                h3= action.subject
                p
                    span= action.part1
                    span , &nbsp
                    span= action.part2
                    span , &nbsp
                    span= action.part3
                    span , &nbsp
                a(href="/delete/#{action._id}",data-theme="a", data-icon="delete") Delete
```

Comment: I kinda lost you at "I would to sort" and the "The order is not important". Do you mean you do not mind if it's in ascending or descending order ?
Anyway, if `actions` is an array, you should sort it server-side, using [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 0):

```
each article in page.articles.reverse()
```

just use .reverse(),which was a js function. jade is a js program.